# v-data-table change color selected row

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I would like to change the background color of the selected row in a v-data-table.

```html
    <v-data-table dense :headers="headers"
    :items="records"
    @click:row="handleClick"> <!-- handleClick is a function that logs item for the moment... -->

    <template v-slot:[`item.index`]="{item}">
        <v-row justify="center">
            <v-col>
                <div>{{item.index}}</div>
            </v-col>
        </v-row>
    </template>

    <template v-slot:[`item.status`]="{ item }">
        <v-row justify="center">

            <v-col v-if="item.status===1">
                <v-icon color="green">
                    mdi-check-circle
                </v-icon>
            </v-col>
            <v-col v-else>
                <v-icon color="orange">
                    mdi-progress-check
                </v-icon>
            </v-col>
        </v-row>
    </template>
</v-data-table>
```

I couldn't find a way to distinguish the selected row from the others and thus update the style for the selected one.
Basically i'd like to reproduce the behavior implemented for the v-list component.

Answer (score 0):

Selected rows have the `v-data-table__selected` class applied on their TR tag - so you can just create some CSS override to target them. The default style in Vuetify is

```css
.theme--light.v-data-table tbody tr.v-data-table__selected 
{
    background: #f5f5f5;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `item-key="index"` and `single-select` to select row and set class `tr.v-data-table__selected`:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data() {
    return {
      headers: [{text: 'index', value: 'index'}, {text: 'status', value: 'status'}],
      records: [{index: 1, status: 1}, {index: 2, status: 0}, {index: 3, status: 1}],
      selected: null
    }
  },
  methods: {
    handleClick(item, row) {
      row.select(true);
      this.selected = item
    }
  }
})
```

```css
tr.v-data-table__selected {
  background: lime !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@6.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-main>
      <v-container>
      <div>{{ selected }}</div>
        <v-data-table dense :headers="headers"
            :items="records" item-key="index" single-select
            @click:row="handleClick"> 
            <template v-slot:[`item.index`]="{item}">
                <v-row justify="center">
                    <v-col>
                        <div>{{item.index}}</div>
                    </v-col>
                </v-row>
            </template>
            <template v-slot:[`item.status`]="{ item }">
                <v-row justify="center">
                    <v-col v-if="item.status===1">
                        <v-icon color="green">
                            mdi-check-circle
                        </v-icon>
                    </v-col>
                    <v-col v-else>
                        <v-icon color="orange">
                            mdi-progress-check
                        </v-icon>
                    </v-col>
                </v-row>
            </template>
        </v-data-table>
      </v-container>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
```